# Nuxt & Vue Social Chat

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, css-variables

I installed the [Vue Social Chat](https://ktquez.github.io/vue-social-chat/?ref=madewithvuejs.com) module into my Nuxt app and having trouble to understand how the props and color setting work. At present everything works fine, although the whatsapp Icon displayed is black as well as the top bar situated inside the speech bubble. How would I go about changing this in Nuxt. The author says to use css variables, but I have no idea where to put these and how to use them in my code.

Nuxt also does not have an App.vue so i just imported the module directly which seems to work but I am not sure I am doing it correctly.

This is what my current default.vue page looks like. I do not import the module any place else.

```html
<template>
  <v-app dark>
    <v-main>
      <Nuxt />
    </v-main>
    <div>
      <SocialChat
        icon
        :attendants="attendants"
      >
        <p slot="header" >Chat to us on whatsapp for any question, or sales related topics.</p>
        <template v-slot:button>
          <img
            src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ktquez/vue-social-chat/master/src/icons/whatsapp.svg"
            alt="icon whatsapp"
            aria-hidden="true"
          >
        </template>
        <small slot="footer">Opening hours: 8am to 6pm</small>
      </SocialChat>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import { SocialChat } from 'vue-social-chat'

export default {
  name: 'DefaultLayout',
  components: {
    SocialChat
  },
  data() {
    return {
      attendants: [
        {
          app: 'whatsapp',
          label: '',
          name: '',
          number: '',
          avatar: {
            src: '',
            alt: ''
          }
        },
        // ...
      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style>
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Importing it in the default layout is totally fine as you did. If you inspect the DOM, you can see that the Whatsapp button is using `.vsc-popup-button--default { background-color: var(--vsc-bg-button) }` so setting the CSS variables [as explained](https://ktquez.github.io/vue-social-chat/setup-v2.html#custom-style) should do the trick. You could either redefine it locally or put it somewhere globally in your CSS, in the `:root` scope (use the devtools to inpect it).

Comment: Could you please give me an example of what this would look like in my <style></style> tags. I really do not know what you mean.

Comment: Ok so after playing around a bit I tried.
```
button.vsc-popup-button.vsc-popup-button--default {
  background-color: green;
}
```
and it seems to work. Not sure if it's the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mainly what is needed overall

```html
<template>
  <div class="layout">
    <nuxt />
    <social-chat id="social-button" icon :attendants="attendants">
      <p slot="header">
        Click on one of our attendants below to chat on WhatsApp.
      </p>
      <template #button>
        <img
          src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ktquez/vue-social-chat/master/src/icons/whatsapp.svg"
          alt="icon whatsapp"
          aria-hidden="true"
        />
      </template>
      <small slot="footer">Opening hours: 8am to 6pm</small>
    </social-chat>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { SocialChat } from 'vue-social-chat'

export default {
  name: 'DefaultLayout',
  components: {
    SocialChat,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      attendants: [
        {
          app: 'whatsapp',
          label: 'Technical support',
          name: 'Alan Ktquez',
          number: '5581983383532',
          avatar: {
            src: 'https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/8084606?s=460&u=20b6499a416cf7129a18e5c168cf387e159edb1a&v=4',
            alt: 'Alan Ktquez avatar',
          },
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style>
:root #social-button {
  --vsc-bg-header: orange;
  --vsc-bg-footer: #fafafa;
  --vsc-text-color-header: yellow;
  --vsc-text-color-footer: green;
  --vsc-bg-button: pink;
  --vsc-text-color-button: purple;
  --vsc-outline-color: #333;
  --vsc-border-color-bottom-header: teal;
  --vsc-border-color-top-footer: #f3f3f3;
}
</style>
```

Instead of `:root #social-button` CSS selector, we may have used `--vsc-bg-button: pink !important;` too but I don't like to nuke CSS specificity.
Also, the style can be `scoped` but there is no really implication here anyway because you will not get any scoping issue here.

A github repo can be found here: https://github.com/kissu/vue-social

And a hosted working example available here: https://so-vue-social.netlify.app/

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. I wish I could give you several up votes. You are amazing! Such a detailed answer.